# Can't install ubuntu after deleting windows "completely?" GRUB intallation error

Tags: 14.04, grub2, system-installation, hard-drive, metadata

I'm leaving windows completely in all my devices, I had no problem installing ubuntu in my laptap, but it's being hard to do it in my desktop, will try to explain the situation:

Hard drives setup: 
2x120gb ssd in raid0 and 2x1TB hdd in raid0 "I want to install in the ssd raid"

I had windows 8.1 installed but in first intallation try, I deleted the windows partition from the linux setup, it says that there are some metadata from windows installation and ask me for restart windows and shut it down again "but I don't have access to the windows system now cause I deleted it..." will attach snapshot about this.

The next thing I did was access run the live linux cd and tried to deleta and format manually the partition "but I get some errors" so I directly deleted the raid volume from the intel raid administration setup, formated individually both drives from the linux live CD "without problems this time" and made the raid volume again.
The thing is that when I try to install ubuntu again, still throws me this error about previous windows installation, and I feel like WTF!!
I supposed that if I delete the raid volume, format the drives individually and then build the raid again, any information in the drives would be erased... but seems no althoug the raid setup says "any content in this drives will be lost"

Any ideas how to leave this ssd drives like factory? Make this thing any sense?

PD: Under any circunstances I want to lose my 2TB raid files
PD2: I read about the fast boot option in windows, but I don't have chance now to recover windows and deactivate that option "I expected drives to be completely clean after described process"

Photo from problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8178ydcshid47q/2015-10-02%2011.43.03.jpg?dl=0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the problem is that your HDD is set to GPT. Which has been happening a lot because of the new UEFI mobo's and Windows 8+.

Can't help you with the Raid situation, but the Ubuntu installer will always refuse to install on GPT HDD's.

Try using the Windows install disk to access repair options. Then open the command prompt and type:

Treat these lines as separate commands. Hit enter after each one.

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk #  ("Where # is equal to the disk number.")
clean
convert mbr</pre>
```

Then exit command prompt and restart with your Ubuntu installer.

Your HDD should now have a master boot record and you should be able to install Ubuntu as normal.

You may not lose everything just by changing the boot record.

Comment: WOW, it worked, so simple, so usefull!! Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: I have used gpt since about 10.10 for BIOS boot and now UEFI boot without issue. With BIOS you do have to have the 1 or 2MB unformatted bios_grub partition or with UEFI the ESP - efi system partition as FAT32 with boot flag(if gparted). But many have issues where the install Windows in BIOS mode to a  previous gpt partitioned drive and Windows does not correctly convert to MBR(msdos). Then you have to run fixparts to remove backup gpt partition table.